# Computer takes 30-35 min to boot after storage resizing

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

My system drive had around 300 MB left, so I installed a partition management software called MiniTool and then went on to shift storage from the E drive to the D drive and then to the C drive.

I realised when I was done with all of it that I had some unallocated space left.

I also gave more space to the reserve storage. The first boot it started the partition like normal. Then it restarted and the first boot was faster than the second. Then after that every time I start my laptop it takes around 30-35 minutes to start.

- Laptop : Dell latitude e5530
- OS: Windows 10 pro  ( the latest one)
- Unallocated space : 2.5 GB
- Total disk space: 498 GB

  1. 31 GB from E to D
  2. 31 GB from D to C
  3. 1 GB from C to reserved

PS: the laptop is also taking really long to shut down or restart.
Windows start menu is being buggy. The Run as Administrator popup takes you to the usual popup screen but there's no popup or display box there and it closes itself after some time.

Comment: I think that you need to provide the size & unallocated space on your C: drive (btw, MiniTools Partition Wizard was an excellent choice).

Comment: From the description of your problem, your performance problems are likely caused by a bad disk  The fact the start menu is buggy confirms you have multiple issues more than likely.

Comment: If it's spending 30-35 minutes, very little of that is actual booting activity.  It's tied up in its underwear dealing with a problem.

Comment: So I recently got into the laptop and I got to remove that unallocated space because I thought it was the reason for the problems . And well, the laptop isn't even starting now